# scala closure - force bind to value not reference

Tags: scala, closures

I have a method that returns an array of simple functions that just print their order number:

```
def buggyClosureFunction(amount: Int) = {
  val functions = new Array[() => Unit](amount);
  var i = 0;
  while (i < amount) {
    functions(i) = {()=>print(i + " ")}
    i += 1;
  }
  functions
}

 val wow = buggyClosureFunction(4);
 wow.foreach(_());
```

This prints 4 4 4 4. ( all functions print the value of `i` that they reference.
I can't seem to change my method so that the returned functions would print 1 2 3 4.

One of my attempts:

```
def goodClosureFunction(amount: Int) = {
  val functions: = new Array[() => Unit](amount);
  var i = 0;
  val helper = (num: Int) => {
    print(num);
  }

  while (i < amount) {
    functions(i) = {()=>helper(i)()}
    i += 1;
  }
  functions
}
```

But this stil prints 4 4 4 4.

Comment: Consider this `def closures(n: Int) = (0 until n) map (i => () => print(i + " "))`, no vars, no unexpected closure problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your closing over `var i = 0` the Scala compiler will turns `i` from `scala.Int` to `scala.runtime.IntRef` and lift it inside it's compiler generated class. This means that generated class holds the reference to the said type. When the function is executed, the value is actually *pointing to the last value*, instead of holding the value of each iteration.

In order to avoid that, create a local copy of `i` inside your closure:

```
while (i < amount) {
  functions(i) = {
    val j = i
    () => print(j + " ")
  }
  i += 1;
}
```

As @Łukasz points out, if you want to go with the functional approach and avoid the closure trouble and mutable state:

```
def nonBuggyNoClosure(n: Int) = (0 until n) map (i => () => print(i + " "))
```

More on the implementation detail of Scala closure in [How are closures implemented in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19806445/how-are-closures-implemented-in-scala)