# structs with boxed vs. unboxed closures

Tags: rust

I'm still internalizing closures in Rust and how to best work with them, so this question might be somewhat vague, and there will perhaps be silly sub-questions. I'm basically looking for proper idioms and maybe even transforming the way I think about how to do some stuff in Rust.

## Storing unboxed closure

The Rust book has an example simple `Cacher` in it's [chapter on closures](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch13-01-closures.html):

```
struct Cacher<T>
where
    T: Fn(u32) -> u32,
{
    calculation: T,
    value: Option<u32>,
}

impl<T> Cacher<T>
where
    T: Fn(u32) -> u32,
{
    fn new(calculation: T) -> Cacher<T> {
        Cacher {
            calculation,
            value: None,
        }
    }

    fn value(&mut self, arg: u32) -> u32 {
        match self.value {
            Some(v) => v,
            None => {
                let v = (self.calculation)(arg);
                self.value = Some(v);
                v
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is supposed to be used like this:

```
let mut c = Cacher::new(|a| a);
let v1 = c.value(1);
```

That is perfectly fine and useful, but what if I need to have this `Cacher` be a member of another struct, say (in the spirit of the Rust book chapter), a `WorkoutFactory`? Since `Cacher` is parameterized by the closure's type, I am forced to parameterize `WorkoutFactory` with the same closure type.

Is my understanding correct? I guess so, the `Cacher` struct structure depends on the type `T` of the calculation, so the struct `WorkoutFactory` structure must depend on the type of `Cacher`. On one hand this feels like a natural, unavoidable and perfectly justified consequence of how closures work in Rust, on the other hand it means that

- `WorkoutFactory` can be contained in another struct that is also forced to be parameterized by `T`, which can be contained in another struct, ... - the closure type spreads like plague. With perhaps other `T`'s coming from deep down the member hierarchy, the signature of the top-level struct can become monstrous.
- the fact that there is some caching involved in `WorkoutFactory` should be just an implementation detail, perhaps the caching was even added at version 2.0, but the type parameter is visible in the public interface of `WorkoutFactory` and needs to be accounted for. The seemingly implementation detail is now part of the interface, no good :(

Is there some way to work around these problems without changing the signature of `Cacher`? How do others cope with this?

## Storing boxed closure

If I want to get rid of the type parameters, I can `Box` the closure. I've come up with the following code:

```
struct BCacher {
    calculation: Box<Fn(u32) -> u32>,
    value: Option<u32>,
}

impl BCacher {
    fn new<T: Fn(u32) -> u32 + 'static>(calculation: T) -> BCacher {
        BCacher {
            calculation: Box::new(calculation),
            value: None,
        }
    }

    fn value(&mut self, arg: u32) -> u32 {
        match self.value {
            Some(v) => v,
            None => {
                let v = (self.calculation)(arg);
                self.value = Some(v);
                v
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can use it exactly like `Cacher`:

```
let mut c = BCacher::new(|a| a);
let v1 = c.value(1);
```

...*almost* :( The `'static'` annotation means I can't do this:

```
let x = 1;
let mut c = BCacher::new(|a| a + x);
```

because the closure may outlive `x`. That is unfortunate, something possible with the non-boxed version is no longer possible with the boxed version.

Furthermore, this version is less efficient, it is necessary to dereference the `Box` (is that correct?), and RAM access is slow. The difference will most probably be negligible in most cases, but still..

I could address the first issue with lifetime annotation:

```
struct BLCacher<'a> {
    calculation: Box<Fn(u32) -> u32 + 'a>,
    value: Option<u32>,
}
```

but now I'm back to `Cacher` with type parameters and all the unpleasant consequences of that.

## The right to choose

This seems like an unfortunate situation. I have two approaches to storing closure in a struct, and each has it's own set of problems. Let's say I'm willing to live with that, and as the author of the awesome fictional `Cacher` crate, I want to present the users with *both* implementations of `Cacher`, the unboxed `Cacher` and the boxed `BCacher`. But I don't want to write the implementation twice. What would be the best way - if there's any at all - to use an existing `Cacher` implementation to implement `BCacher`?

On a related note (maybe it is even the same question), let's assume I have a

```
struct WorkoutFactory<T>
where
    T: Fn(u32) -> u32,
{
    cacher: Cacher<T>,
}
```

Is there a way to implement `GymFactory` without type parameters that would contain - for private purposes - `WorkoutFactory` with type parameters, probably stored in a `Box`?

## Summary

A long question, sorry for that. Coming from Scala, working with closures is a LOT less straightforward in Rust. I hope I've explained the struggles I've not yet found satisfactory answers to.

Comment: Most closely a duplicate of [How can I avoid a ripple effect from changing a concrete struct to generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44912349/155423)

Comment: Thank you for the link, didn't stumble upon that one during my research. If I understand correctly, I got the various tradeoffs basically right. I can either live with the `T` parameter or `'a` lifetime parameter or limit the closure to `'static`. `Cacher<T>` is not convertible to `BCacher` in any way, and there are no further tricks to help cope with the situation. Is that right?

Comment: You can do what scala does when [a closure captures local `var`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19811263/2731452) to use local variable in a `'static` closure. That is wrap the variable in `Rc` and move a clone of it into the closure. You don't need to do it for `Copy` types though. `let mut c = BCacher::new(move |a| a + x);` compiles.

Comment: @red75prime Thanks for the suggestion, that could help in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer sorry, but in this bit of code here:

```rust
let x = 1;
let mut c = BCacher::new(|a| a + x);
```

Why not change it to:

```rust
let x = 1;
let mut c = BCacher::new(move |a| a + x);
```

That way the functor will absorb and own 'x', so there won't be any reference to it, which should hopefully clear up all the other issues.